# Routing with form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Now I am trying to set a form on the page of index.html.erb(members). I want the form to show the result of searching and want it not to move to other pages. I want to show the result on index.html.erb(members) itself.

But the code below makes the application move to show.html(members) after pushing the search button. I have no idea why this happens. Could you give me some advice?

Now I am trying to set search window based on my textbook. But I failed with the error message below. I don't understand the cause although this is just a syntax error. Could you give me some advice?

☆index.html.erb(members controller)

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>
<p>※登録されているメンバーのリストです。</p>

<%= form_tag :action => 'index' do %>
 <div class = "field">
  <%= label_tag 'place', '活動場所：'　%><br />
  <%= text_field_tag 'place' %>
 </div> 
 <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
<% end %>

<%= @places_field %>
```

☆members controller

```
def index
    if !checklogin? then return end #
      @members = Member.all
      @places_field = Member.where("place = ?", params[:place])

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json
     end 
  end
```

☆routes.rb

```
MiniSNS::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :group_message_comments

  resources :group_messages do
    resources :group_message_comments
  end

  root :to => 'members#login'
  match '/groups/join'
  resources :group_messages

  resources :groups do 
  resources :group_messages
  end

  match '/members/new'


  resources :index
  resources :groups
  post 'groups/:id' => 'group#show'
  post '/groups/new'
  post '/index/index'

  match '/members/login'
  match '/members/logout'
  match '/members/friend'
  match '/members/show'
  post '/messages/comment'

  resources :comments
  resources :messages
  resources :friends
  resources :members

 #OmniAuth
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#callback"
  match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as => :logout
  match '/auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to adding `remote => true` on your `submit_tag` like:

```
<%= submit_tag '検索', :remote => true %>
```

Then on your controller, adding return to js with:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json
  format.js
end
```

Create new view called `index.js.erb` and fill that file with Javascript code to update your place field, the simplest way is like:

On **index.html.erb** make sure you have this kind of code:

```
<div id="place_field_section"><%= render 'place_field' %></div>
```

Of course you should have a partial called `_place_field.html.erb` for example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Foo</th>
    <th>Bar</th>
  </tr>

<% @place_fields.each do |place_field| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= place_field.foo %></td>
    <td><%= place_field.bar %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

then on your **index.js.erb**:

```
$("#place_field_section").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('place_field')) %>");
```

Is this what you intent to? Please correct me if I'm wrong.